# Reference on Lipschitz property of the infimum of a family of Lipschitz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, nonlinear-optimization, lipschitz-functions, non-convex-optimization

I can prove the following fact:  the infimum, or supremum, of any family of L-Lipschitz functions is L-Lipschitz, as long as the constant L is fixed.

However, since this is a very basic result, I am interested in a reference where it is proved.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This property is called "lattice completeness" or "Dedekind completeness". Maybe you find a reference if you search for these terms, but it's possibly one of these results for which no one bothered to write down a proof, because they are just so simple.

Comment: @JohnD Did you ever find a reference to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N. Weaver, *Lipschitz Algebras*, 2018 (second edition), Proposition 1.32, p. 22.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. I realise it came a little to late, but maybe it will be helpful for somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

You may not find this in a text but it is an easy
consequence of the following: $\max\{f,g\}=\frac {f+g+|f-g|} 2$, $\min\{f,g\}=\frac {f+g-|f-g|} 2$ and $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$.

Comment: thanks, but I already know how to prove it. What I need is a reference.

Comment: @JohnD: If you have a proof, you don't need a reference :)